# Fork pseudoterminal in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, terminal, pty

I am looking to write a terminal emulator with .NET Core and SFML.NET - without a library such as libvterm. To do so, I tried code such as:

```cs
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    FileName = "/bin/zsh"
};

var ShellProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo = startInfo
};

ShellProcess.Start();
ShellProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
ShellProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

However, this doesn't pass me the escape sequences or anything like that. Is there a way I can fork a pseudoterminal (like [node-pty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pty)) in .NET Core on macOS?

Comment: Unfortunately the best way *I* could find to do this in .NET Core was to create a tiny node script that uses node-pty and dumps the output including escape chars onto std out, then read that from C#, which invokes node as a sub-process. Not great at all.